# Loop appears to end, even though expectation is to reset

Tags: jquery, each

I have an object:

```
var $neutrals = [
    {label : "Neutrals 1", value : "#ffffff", type : "color"},
    {label : "Neutrals 2", value : "#f8f8f8", type : "color"},
    {label : "Neutrals 3", value : "#d9d9d9", type : "color"},
    {label : "Neutrals 4", value : "#b2b3b7", type : "color"},
    {label : "Neutrals 5", value : "#5b5e65", type : "color"},
    {label : "Neutrals 6", value : "#151618", type : "color"}
];
```

Within this object, I'm looking to loop through each element to then compare each color with each other to make sure that that pair passes a certain luminance level. Here is my code:

```
function create_colors(){
    var neutral_set = $("<div/>").addClass("color-set");
    $(".color-container").html(neutral_set);
    neutral_set.append("<h3>Neutrals</h3>");

    $.each($neutrals, function(){
        var parent_color = this.value;

        var colorstrip = $("<div/>").addClass("color-strip").attr("style", "background-color:"+parent_color+";");

        neutral_set.append(colorstrip);

        $.each($neutrals, function(){
            var overlay = hexToRgb(this.value);
            var base = hexToRgb(parent_color)

            var diff_contrast = contrast(base, overlay);
            console.log(this.value+", "+parent_color);

            if(diff_contrast > 4.5)
            {
                colorstrip.append("<span style='color:"+this.value+"'>"+this.label+", "+diff_contrast+"</span>");
                return false;
            }
        })
    });
}
```

The output appears like so:
[image]

This is close to what I expected it to be, where all the lighter colors show the lowest to pass the 4.5:1 contrast ratio, while the darker gray and blacks are empty without showing, from my experience, the white `#ffffff`. Is it that I'm stopping the loop with a return false that's stopping the loop from continuing? I'm not entirely sure what I did wrong here.

Comment: Hi, it seems there are 6 lines, one for each element. The last items didn't match the `diff_contrast > 4.5` condition it seems so that extra text didn't get appended for those.

Comment: Yeah but that can't be, because 100% guarantee that white (#ffffff) will pass with a minimum of 4.5 with the black (#151618)

Comment: As soon as this is true: `diff_contrast > 4.5` then `return false` terminates the function. If there any other colors the meet this criteria further down the array, it'll never reach them.

Comment: But isn't it supposed to loop through all the colors first, and within that, loop again and test per each one until it hits the first contrast of 4.5? ie: aren't the last two colors supposed to go through the same loop too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jspcal's comment is correct. The last two iterations don't ever meet the condition so the span never gets appended.

I would guess that you're not compensating for inversed parameters in your `contrast` function. For example:

```
contrast([255,255,255], [101,94,91]) //Gives 6.493852249020362
contrast([101,94,91], [255,255,255]) //Gives 0.1539918004988266
```

Try modifying the `contrast` function to allow for this condition:

```
function contrast(rgb1, rgb2) { 
    var result = (luminanace(rgb1.r, rgb1.g, rgb1.b) + 0.05) /
                 (luminanace(rgb2.r, rgb2.g, rgb2.b) + 0.05);

    if (result < 1) result = 1/result;
    return result;
}
```

[Here's a jsFiddle of this solution.](https://jsfiddle.net/L3hvcwj2/1/)

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks!